# Django field validation warnings

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I am new to Django and confronted with the following problem:

Usually I have a form where I have defined my fields and according validation rules.

Usually there are fields which have potentially invalid inputs. These are then validated and an error is shown in case. An invalid form leads to the expected behaviour that the data isn't persisted to the database.

Now I have a form where I have strict validation rules which should lead (to displaying) an error and data not persisting to the database and besides I have looser validation rules which should lead to displaying of a warning/hint but persisting to the database.

Example

I have a list where the user could enter how many male, female and diverse participants were in a given course. Later on I ask questions about how many male, female and diverse partcipants would like to do another course from our program.

There may be inconsistencies at the moment which I want to warn about but nevertheless accept / save the data as given.

Is there any mechanics in Django which allows displaying "warnings", "hints" etc. per field like the error messages?

Comment: As far as I know, no. Although it might be possible to reuse Django's validation system for a large part to include this. But the main issue might be how to *display* these rules: given the form is valid, but perhaps not ideal (as in violates hints), it will thus create/update a record, so how would you notify the user about these hints?

Comment: I think the strict validation rules are no problem with using `clean_<fieldname>()` and `clean()` method. For the looser validation I would put that logic in the view itself.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I have a "hackish way" in as far as I abuse class variables atm. I have a form with `_warnings` which could be read from while rendering the form. The display-part was the easiest part.

Comment: @ThomasJunk: well the main problem can be a violation of the [*Post/Redirect/Get*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) flow, which can result in a refresh of the page creating a second (unwanted) record. So to do this in a "clean" way, it needs to persist the form somehow between the POST, redirect, and the next GET request. That is of course possible, for example if the form can load an instance, and then perform the cleaning on the existing values.

Comment: @Tarquinius Thanks for the hint. I might be going that road down.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Yeah. That is a can of worms as I found out. Having it as a class variable causes interesting side effects XD

Comment: If you are using django forms and django views like FormView, you don't need to hack your form with strict validation, what you can do is have 2 forms - 1 validate form for errors and 2 validates for warnings. In this case you want to extend view. On both forms you call `is_valid()` and then access result via `.errors`.